# SP - How to set a unique row number programaticallly

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, .net

I want to count all list items in my dynamic list to **set ID** For Every NEW RECORD. How to do this?

```
 int cnt = 0;
 int c = 0;
  foreach (TableRow tr in allVisibleRows)
  {
     SPListItem itemAdd = wayList.Items.Add();

      if (cnt == 0)
      {
         c = itemAdd.ListItems.Count..... My Logic Not work...
      }    

      temAdd["wayNum"] = "№ " + c;

   }

   cnt++;

   itemAdd.Update();
```

**Like this picture:**

[image: screenshot]

Every next RECORD , not a ROW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a couple of approaches:

1. Save last item id in SPList properties and then retrieve the value next time you're adding an item:

> ```
> //set - after setting all field values and updating the item
> itemAdd.Update();
> wayList.RootFolder.SetProperty("LastItemID", itemAdd.ID); 
> //you need AddProperty if it doesn't exist
> //get
> //then subtract 1 if needed
> var itemId = wayList.RootFolder.GetProperty("LastItemID");
> ```

2. Get item id by calling `Update()` on the item. Keep in mind that doing any additional changes will require another `Update()` call which might be resource inefficient:

> ```
> SPListItem itemAdd = wayList.Items.Add();
> itemAdd.Update();
> var itemAddId = itemAdd.ID;
> itemAdd = wayList.GetItemById(itemAddId); 
> //otherwise you might get save conflicts
> itemAdd["wayNum"] = itemAddId; //-1 if needed
> ```

An example specific to your problem:

```
int cnt = 0;
int c = 0;
var properties = wayList.RootFolder.Properties;

foreach (TableRow tr in allVisibleRows)
{
    SPListItem itemAdd = wayList.Items.Add();

    if (properties.ContainsKey("LastItemID"))
    {
        var lastItemId = Convert.ToInt32(wayList.RootFolder.GetProperty("LastItemID"));
        itemAdd["wayNum"] = lastItemId + 1;
        //set new property value
        wayList.RootFolder.SetProperty("LastItemID", lastItemId + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        //property doesn't exist - start from 0
        wayList.RootFolder.AddProperty("LastItemID", "0");
    }
}

//save properties
wayList.RootFolder.Update();
```

Update 2:
Apparently this was SP2007 which doesn't have SPFolder Get/Set Property extension methods. The IDs had to be the same for every batch of items. This was the final code:

```
var properties = wayList.RootFolder.Properties;

var lastItemId = 1;
if (properties.ContainsKey("LastItemID"))
{
lastItemId = Convert.ToInt32(properties["LastItemID"]);
}
else
{
//property doesn't exist - start from 1
wayList.RootFolder.Properties.Add("LastItemID", "1");
}

foreach (TableRow tr in allVisibleRows)
{
SPListItem itemAdd = wayList.Items.Add();
itemAdd["wayNum"] = lastItemId + 1;
itemAdd.Update();
}

//set new property value
wayList.RootFolder.Properties["LastItemID"] = lastItemId.ToString();
wayList.RootFolder.Update();
```

Comment: Thank you, but my case is different..

Comment: The first example would perfectly fit your case - if the property doesn't exist, you start from number one and assign it to an item, next time you increment by one, save the property for later use.

Comment: How to I do this, please you show me how to do this with my code. Thank you previously...

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: RootFolder.SetProperty is missing ?

Comment: It's not, the code is working - I am using something similar in my solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38960/discussion-between-goshuy-and-paul-strupeikis).

Comment: Look above -> last picture in my post for this problem...

Comment: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.Int16.Parse(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider) at System.Convert.ToInt16(Object value) at WayBillModule.btnAdd_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: Means that you might not be storing numbers in the RootFolder Properties. Debug your code and see what's going on at this line - lastItemId = Convert.ToInt32(properties["LastItemID"]);

Answer (score 3):

You can perform this activity using CAML query with the below logic

1. Get the list items in descending order
2. Set row limit as one and retrive the record

CAML Query:

```
<View><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False'/></OrderBy>
      <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value Type='Text'></Value> </Eq> </Where> </Query>
      <RowLimit>1</RowLimit>
</View>
```

You will get the ID of the last item inserted in the list using above steps.

Now you can now increment that number easily.

**Try this Update code**

```
SPListItem itemAdd = wayList.Items.Add();
int cnt = wayList.ItemCount;
int nextNumber = cnt + 1;
temAdd["wayNum"] = "№ " + nextNumber;
itemAdd.Update();
```

Comment: is above code works for you?

Comment: Please upload image somewhere else...

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/O0HQ2b1.png?1

Comment: It is not row number of SharePoint List item. It is basically a custom code.